# Render view while processing data

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.5

I'm on Play Framework 2.5.14, with play for java.

I have a Service that loads and processes some data, and it takes a long time to process that data.

I'm doing it this way:

`Controller`

```
public Result showData() {
    List<Data> data = service.getProcessedData();

    return ok(views.html.data.render(data));
}
```

`View`

```
@(data: List[Data])

<!-- html code -->
```

But when I go to the page it is in blank a long time because `service.getProcessData()` takes too long. When the function finish, then the view is rendered.

What I need is for the view to load and when the data is ready, fill the view.

Comment: Can the service use Akka Streams to process the data? I mean, instead of waiting for all the data to be ready to render, render as soon as part of it is ready.

Comment: It is impossible for me to use Akka for that process. I had thought about whether it would be possible to use Future, `CompletableFuture`, etc. in this but I do not know how to implement it with `Result` and the view.

Comment: If you are using Akka Streams, you can use streamed or chunked results.

Comment: I cannot use Akka Streams... I thought of to add a route where I can retrieve that processed data and fetch it on the view itself.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? I am having a similar issue. If you did, could you please post something to help us struggling :)

Comment: I did not find a solution using Play. What I do is to render the view, and in the view itself I call an `ajax petition` in javascript/jquery to get the slow data. Hope this can help you, it is the only solution that I liked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in comments, I did not find a solution using Play.

What I do is to render the view, and in the view itself I call an `ajax` petition in javascript/jquery to get the slow data.

Hope this can help, it is the only solution that I liked.