# play framework - render view while doing processing/redirect after X seconds

Tags: java, asynchronous, playframework, routes, playframework-2.0

*note: I am new to play framework*

For my Play! project, I require some form of asynchronous programming. Simply, I need to display a view, whilst doing processing in the background, followed by a redirect or a new form being rendered.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44056366/render-view-while-processing-data) has been asked with no response. I have had a look on the Play Documentation pages, I didn't find any solution there.

**What I have tried:**

I attempted to modify the `AsynchController` that is given with the `play starter example`. However when navigating to `http://localhost/message` , the function seemed to act more as a sleep instead of a scheduled task which is set and "forgotten" about, i.e. one can continue on with further coding.

**AsynchController snippet:** with own modification

```
public CompletionStage<Result> message() {
        return getFutureMessage(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).thenApplyAsync(s -> ok(views.html.User.Account.verified.render()), exec);
    }

    private CompletionStage<String> getFutureMessage(long time, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
        actorSystem.scheduler().scheduleOnce(
            Duration.create(time, timeUnit),
            () -> future.complete("Waiting 5 seconds..."),
            exec
        );
        return future;
    }
```

route entry

```
GET     /message                 controllers.AsyncController.message
```

**Purpose:**

My aim here was for the message `Waiting 5 seconds...` to be displayed, followed by a +/- 5s delay. Thereafter it would reach the "future" (is this correct?) whereby it would render a view (or redirect to a controller), in this case the `verified` page ( for account verified).

Am I on the right track with my original goal, where can I get a good example of something similar?

Comment: Are you using any client logic to handle the server responses?

Comment: Unless using chunked response with specific rendering logic on the client side, I doubt there is any solution to return multiple responses in this way

Comment: @cchantep could you please define what you mean by "client side" in terms of Play Framework. What would be client side and what would be "server side" (I assume that server side functions are executing the Controller's code, routing to controllers)

Comment: client side = anything in the browser (not Play specific)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a simple solution, but you have to set up 2 entries in route.

The first entry displays the message "Waiting 5 seconds...", while at the same time it give an AJAX call to the second one. The controller for the second entry does the calculation/sleep for 5 seconds, and returns the desired content, which will be rendered on the first page by Javascript.

In the first webpage you would put something like:

```
  axios.get(second-url)
      .then(function (response) {
        document.getElementById(someplaceholder).innerHTML=response.data.
      })
```

Comment: Could this be extended for use of e.g. editing your profile where various submenus exist and a "placeholder" ia replaced by the submenu's options when clicked, as seen in github's edit profile page?

Comment: Sure. You would make each submenu give an AJAX call then.  But in the case of Github, looking at the url bar,  every submenu seems point to different urls, so it's just a normal http request, not AJAX.